# GitHub - Should I unassign an issue once closed?

Tags: version-control, github, source-code, issue-tracking

Whenever I am using issue tracking on GitHub with my team, should we unassign people from the issue once we close it?

I don't know which way should be done, and if there is any advantage to unassigning members.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general you don't want to unassign an issue if it's closed.

There are two reasons why you don't want to do it:

- If an issue is reopened then you want the original people to be involved
- You want have have some history who worked on what (not in the keep track of productivity sense but more on whom do I ask if I have questions, what else might have changed while solving the issue)

Bonus reason: never try to optimize your process so much that it involves extra steps. Unless you have a clear reason why unassigning gives you any benefit why bother (and people will forget if you make them do meaningless administration).

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge! I will take that info into use.